# Are there any dependencies for PS.js (Project Server JSOM)?

Tags: spfx, jsom, spfx-webparts, project-server

Because I [can't seem to do what I need to get done using the REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/272500/8992), I am going to try to use the Project Server JSOM in an SPFx webpart.

I found instructions on how to load the SharePoint JSOM into an SPFx web part by using `SPComponentLoader`, but [that example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/connect-to-sharepoint-using-jsom#load-sharepoint-jsom-scripts-by-using-spcomponentloader) shows `SP.js` as having several dependencies that need to be loaded first:

- `init.js`
- `MicrosoftAjax.js`
- `SP.Runtime.js`

The [example I found](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/project/getting-started-with-the-project-server-2013-javascript-object-model#retrieving-the-projects-collection) of how to get started using the Project Server JSOM only talks about loading the `PS.js` file:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="PS.js" runat="server" ondemand="false" localizable="false" loadafterui="true" />
```

and then making sure it's loaded by using `executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded`:

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(MyFunction, "PS.js");
```

with no mention of any dependencies.

The [MS documentation for PS.js Javascript library](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/project-javascript-api/jj668539%28v%3Doffice.15%29) also does not mention any dependencies.

So, are there any unmentioned dependencies I would need to load before `PS.js` in order to use the Project Server JSOM in SPFx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer.  Started playing around with it by only loading `PS.js`, but when trying to do a simple

```
const ctx = new PS.ProjectContext('https://server/pwa/my-pwa-instance');
```

I got a reference error `'SP' is not defined`.  So if `SP` is required, I figured *all* the other dependencies are required as well.

```
private componentDidMount = (): void => {
    SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/init.js', {
        globalExportsName: '$_global_init'
    })
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
        return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js', {
            globalExportsName: 'Sys'
        });
    })
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
        return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js', {
            globalExportsName: 'SP'
        });
    })
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
        return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/SP.js', {
            globalExportsName: 'SP'
        });
    })
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
        return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/PS.js', {
            globalExportsName: 'PS'
        });
    })
    .then((): void => {
        // do my other init stuff
    });
}
```

After loading all dependencies like this, creating a new `PS.ProjectContext` at the very least seems to work.