# How to set enterprise custom field values on a particular (new) task using Project Server JSOM?

Tags: spfx-webparts, project-server

I'm creating an SPFx web part that reads tasks from one project file stored in Project Server, gets some values from those tasks (including the values of some *local* custom fields), and then creates new tasks in a *different* project on Project Server, in which the values of the local custom fields are stored in *enterprise* custom fields.

Because I [couldn't get everything I needed to do working using the REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/272500/8992) directly, I resorted to using the Project Server JSOM library (`PS.js`), which [I was able to get working in SPFx](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/274713/8992).

Now I'm able to create new tasks in the project using the JSOM syntax, which includes creating a new `PS.TaskCreationInformation` object, setting some properties on that object, and then adding that to the task collection in a draft project.  However, the [options for what properties you can set](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/project-javascript-api/jj669418(v=office.15)) on a `TaskCreationInformation` object are limited.  So I need to subsequently update the task's enterprise custom fields with the correct values.

I can't seem to find any information on how to do this.  All of the [things](https://nearbaseline.com/2013/08/updating-project-server-custom-fields-via-jsom-csom/) [I've](https://nearbaseline.com/2013/08/updating-lookup-table-values-using-jsom/) [found](http://blog.vitalyzhukov.ru/en/project-server-csom-custom-fields.aspx) online about "updating enterprise custom fields" are all about updating what I would consider the field *definition* on the project itself, not about updating the values for a particular task.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
private createDraftTasks = (tasks: any[]): Promise<any[]> => {
    return new Promise<any[]> ((resolve, reject) => {
        if (tasks.length > 0) {
            const task = tasks.shift();
            const newTaskInfo = new PS.TaskCreationInformation();
            newTaskInfo.set_name(task.Name);
            newTaskInfo.set_start(task.Start);
            newTaskInfo.set_finish(task.Finish);
            newTaskInfo.set_duration(task.Duration);
            const draftTask = this.draftProj.get_tasks().add(newTaskInfo);
            this.psCtx.load(draftTask);
            this.psCtx.executeQueryAsync(() => {
                // i figure this is where i would need to add the values, since
                // i can't really do it on the TaskCreationInformation object, can I?
                // or is there a way to do it that way?

                // i've tried setting it this way, but this doesn't seem to work:
                draftTask.MyEnterpriseCustomField = task.localCustomFieldValue;

                // and I've tried setting it this way, and this defintiely throws an error:
                draftTask.set_MyEnterpriseCustomField(task.localCustomFieldValue);

                // also with camelCasing the field name, still throws an error:
                draftTask.set_myEnterpriseCustomField(task.localCustomFieldValue);

                const updateJob = this.draftProj.update();
                this.psCtx.waitForQueueAsync(updateJob, 5, (status) => {
                    if (status === 4) {
                        this.createDraftTasks(tasks).then((result: any[]) => {
                            resolve([draftTask, ...result]);
                        }).catch(err => {
                            console.log(`fail after task "${task.Name}"`, err);
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log(`update fail after "${task.Name}" with code ${status}`);
                    }
                });
            }, (sender, args) => {
                console.log(`task "${task.Name}" fail`);
                console.log(sender);
                console.log(args);
            });
        } else {
            resolve([]);
        }
    });
}
```

What is the correct Project Server JSOM syntax for setting the value of an enterprise custom field on a particular task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I *finally* found the answer in [this post](http://sharepointstore.com/2016/11/15/update-custom-column-task-project-online/).  The way to set an enterprise custom field value on a task is

```
draftTask.set_item('Custom Field Internal Name', 'your value');
```

If you know the GUID of the draft task, you can get it by doing

```
draftProject.get_tasks().getByGuid('guid');
```

however in my case, I am creating *new* tasks, so I can't know the GUID until I `ctx.load()` the task.  That meant figuring out a complicated order of operations in order to get everything to work, and in fact the code I posted in my question above does not actually work (I think maybe because I load the draft task before I update the project?).

The order of operations I finally figured out to get this all working is this:

- Create all the new (draft) tasks by calling `draftProject.get_tasks().add(taskCreationInfo)`
- Keep a reference to the unresolved/unloaded draft task(s) returned from that function.
- Update the draft project to actually create/save the new tasks.
- Load all the unresolved/unloaded draft tasks.
- Now that they're loaded, you can access their properties, and update the enterprise custom field values.
- Update the draft project *again* to save the updates to the custom fields on all the draft tasks.

Here's the code I ended up with that is working.  Keep in mind that by the time the `createNewTasks` function is called to kick off the whole process, I have already created a Project Server JSOM context object, and checked out the project so it is in a draft project state.

```
public createNewTasks = (newTasks: any[], httpClient: HttpClient) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const tasksCopy: any[] = [...newTasks];
        this.createDraftTasks(tasksCopy).then((draftTasks: any[]) => {

            // i needed the guids of the newly created tasks
            const newTaskIds: string[] = draftTasks.map((taskInfo: any) => {
                return taskInfo.draft.get_id().toString();
            });

            this.updateDraftTasks(draftTasks, httpClient).then(() => {
                this.updateAndCheckinProject().then(() => {
                    resolve(newTaskIds);
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                    reject(err);
                });
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
                reject(err);
            });
        });
    });
}
private createDraftTasks = (tasks: any[]): Promise<any[]> => {
    return new Promise<any[]> ((resolve, reject) => {
        const draftTasks = [];
        tasks.forEach(task => {
            // set what values we can initially with task creation information
            const newTaskInfo = new PS.TaskCreationInformation();
            newTaskInfo.set_name(task.Name);
            newTaskInfo.set_start(task.Start);
            newTaskInfo.set_finish(task.Finish);
            newTaskInfo.set_duration(task.Duration);
            // keep a ref to the draft task
            const draft = this.draftProj.get_tasks().add(newTaskInfo);
            // need to keep the draft task associated with the correct object
            // that has the other data that needs to go in the enterprise custom fields
            // because we need to load the draft tasks before we can update them
            draftTasks.push({
                task,
                draft
            });
        });
        const updateJob: any = this.draftProj.update();
        this.psCtx.waitForQueueAsync(updateJob, 20, (updateStatus) => {
            if (updateStatus === 4) {
                // now that the draft tasks have actually been created by
                // updating the project, need to load them so i can
                // get their guids and update their enterprise custom fields
                this.loadDraftTasks(draftTasks).then((loadedTasks: any[])=> {
                    resolve(loadedTasks);
                });
            } else {
                reject({
                    error: {
                        message: `Adding new tasks failed with error code ${updateStatus}`
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    })
}
private loadDraftTasks = (draftTasks: any[]): Promise<any[]> => {
    return new Promise<any[]> ((resolve, reject) => {
        if (draftTasks.length > 0) {
            const taskInfo = draftTasks.shift();
            this.psCtx.load(taskInfo.draft);
            this.psCtx.executeQueryAsync(() => {
                this.loadDraftTasks(draftTasks).then((result: any[]) => {
                    resolve([{
                        task: taskInfo.task,
                        draft: taskInfo.draft
                    }, ...result]);
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    reject(err);
                });
            }, (sender, args) => {
                const message = args.get_message();
                console.log(message);
                reject(message);
            })
        } else {
            resolve([]);
        }
    });
}
private updateDraftTasks = (draftTasks: any[], httpClient: HttpClient): Promise<any[]> => {
    return new Promise<any[]> ((resolve, reject) => {
        const customFieldsUri = `${strings.ProjectSiteBaseUrl}/_api/ProjectServer/CustomFields?$select=Name,InternalName`;
        httpClient.get(customFieldsUri, HttpClient.configurations.v1, {
            headers: {
                accept: 'application/json'
            }
        }).then((response: HttpClientResponse) => {
            response.json().then(fieldsJSON => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    const enterpriseCustomField_1 = fieldsJSON.value.filter(fld => fld.Name === strings.EnterpriseField1_DisplayName)[0];
                    const enterpriseCustomField_2 = fieldsJSON.value.filter(fld => fld.Name === strings.EnterpriseField2_DisplayName)[0];
                    draftTasks.forEach(taskInfo => {
                        // set the enterprise custom field values by using set_item()
                        taskInfo.draft.set_item(enterpriseCustomField_1.InternalName, taskInfo.task.Field_1_Value);
                        taskInfo.draft.set_item(enterpriseCustomField_2.InternalName, taskInfo.task.FIeld_2_Value);
                    });
                    // save the new field values by updating the project
                    const updateJob = this.draftProj.update();
                    this.psCtx.waitForQueueAsync(updateJob, 20, (status) => {
                        if (status === 4) {
                            console.log('update succeeded');
                            resolve();
                        } else {
                            reject({
                                error: {
                                    message: `Updating fields on tasks failed with error code ${status}`
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    reject(fieldsJSON);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
draftTask["MyEnterpriseCustomField"] = task.localCustomFieldValue;
```

Assuming `MyEnterpriseCustomField` is your field name.